# How to install crown molding or valance board around a cabinet?

Tags: kitchens, trim, cabinets

I am replacing the cabinets in my kitchen and am going to be installing some crown molding (actually a valance board and then crown molding) around the top of the cabinets, as in this picture.

[image: cabinet valance board]

The front part of the wall cabinet sticks out a fraction of an inch (about 1/4) from the side of the cabinet. It appears in this picture they just left a gap and installed the crown molding at an angle across the side of the cabinet. Is this the 'standard' way to handle the fact that the cabinet is not perfectly square/rectangle, or is there a better way to handle the fact that the front sticks out a little further then the sides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the gap bothers you that much, you have a few options.

### Fill the gap

You could fill the gap with wood putty, or color matched caulk. You'll still have a gap, but it will be difficult to see.

### Remove material from the molding

You could remove a bit of the material from the back of the molding, to allow it to lay flat over the lip of the cabinet. This will likely make the mitered joint between the two pieces of molding look odd, as the bottom of the pieces will not mate.

### Remove material from the cabinet

You could remove a bit of the material from the cabinet, to allow the molding to lay flush with the side of the cabinet. Depending on how far out the cabinet overhangs, this might also look a bit strange.

### Learn to live with it

The easiest approach, is to simply learn to ignore it. Not many folks will notice it, and after some time you probably won't either.

Comment: We went with caulking and it looks fine. Even in places where no caulk was applied yet we dont really notice anymore unless looking for it.

Answer (score 1):

1/4" trim strips are made by the kitchen cabinet manufacturer. The 1/4" strips are made to fill the gap. They are fastened on before crown is applied. They are very inexpensive.
If kitchen cabinets are in the process of being ordered, there also is an optional upgrade available to order cabinets with flush finished sides, which do not have the 1/4" gap.
We just ordered our cabinets and the best advice I can give you is to get a copy of the Cabinet specification guide. It has every single thing thats orderable and the best part is you can check the what the salesperson has planned and see if there are other things you want.